# What is the inversion of the Shunting Yard algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, parsing

Dijkstra's [Shunting Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) is used to parse an infix notation and generate [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) output.

I am looking for the opposite, a way to turn RPN into highschool-math-class style infix notation, in order to represent RPN expressions from a database to lay users in an understandable way.

Please save your time and don't cook up the algorithm yourselves, just point me to textbook examples that I can't seem to find. Working backwards from the Shunting Yard algorithm and using my knowledge about the notations I'll probably be able to work up a solution. I'm just looking for a quick shortcut, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Oh, and please don't tag this as "homework", I *swear* I'm out of school already! ;-)

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052960/converting-from-postfix-to-infix) some interesting stuff on the subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since RPN is also known as postfix notation, I tried googling [convert "postfix to infix"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=convert+%22postfix+to+infix%22&btnG=Search) and got quite a few results.  The first several have code examples, but I found the [RubyQuiz entry](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz148.html) particularly enlightening.

Answer (score 7):

If you're not worried about removing redundant parentheses, then the following Lisp code will work:

```
(defun rpn-to-inf (pre)
  (if (atom pre)
      pre
      (cond ((eq (car (last pre)) 'setf)
         (list (rpn-to-inf (first pre)) '= (rpn-to-inf (second pre))))
        ((eq (car (last pre)) 'expt)
         (list (rpn-to-inf (first pre)) '^ (rpn-to-inf (second pre))))
        (t (list (rpn-to-inf (first pre)) 
             (car (last pre)) 
             (rpn-to-inf (second pre)))))))
```

Comment: An implementation in Lisp that may output too many parentheses. Absolutely brilliant on so many levels...