# Converting from postfix to infix

Tags: algorithm

What would be a good algorithm for converting from postfix to infix? 
I've searched and searched but I only get algorithms for converting from infix to postfix. They're going to be decently similar algorithms correct? I also want to incorporate parenthesis. For example, (((13 - 1) / 2)(3 + 5)). 
Thank you!

Comment: Maintain a stack
1. if you read a value push it to stack
2. if you read an operator, pop 2 values(say a,b) and push "(a operator b)" back to stack 
Seems like it will do

Answer (score 6):

Here's the postfix version:-

```
13 1 - 2 / 3 5 + *
```

To convert, parse it like an ordinary postfix parser, but store elements on the stack as a string, not as values:-

```
"13"
"1"
"-"
```

when you get an operator, like above, convert to a single string and put parenthesis around it:-

```
"(13-1)"
```

continuing:-

```
"(13-1)"
"2"
"/"
```

becomes:-

```
"((13-1)/2)"
```

continuing:-

```
"((13-1)/2)"
"3"
"5"
"+"
```

becomes:-

```
"((13-1)/2)"
"(3+5)"
```

finally:-

```
"((13-1)/2)"
"(3+5)"
"*"
```

ends up as:-

```
"((13-1)/2)*(3+5)"
```

you could treat "*" as a special case and omit it from the combined version.

Comment: Side-note: While this approach will always produce the correct result, it won't always produce an aesthetically desirable result due to the potential introduction of unnecessary parenthesis (e.g. for "1 2 3 + +").
In order to introduce parenthesis only when really needed, you also have to keep track of the operators (if any) that produced the results on your stack of strings (this tracking can conveniently be done in a second stack or by using a single stack of pairs that contains the string and the associated operator)

Answer (score 1):

We start with an empty stack. Assuming the postfix expression is correct :

- Read the atomic tokens and put them on stack
- when you reach an operator, pop n elements from the stack where n is the arity of the operator, format it correctly, put the brackets around it and push the resolution back to the stack
- when there's nothing to read, the stack should contain exactly one element with the result

For instance :

input : `2,3,+,5,-,8,*`

Stack contains after each step :

```
 2
 2,3
 (2+3)
 (2+3),5
 ((2+3)-5)
 ((2+3)-5),8
 (((2+3)-5)*8)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach

```
while(input.hasNext()) {
   symbol = input.readNextSymbol(); // read the whole token
   if (symbol is operand) {
      stack.push(symbol)
   } else { // the symbol is an operator
      if (stack.count < 2) {
          ERROR too few operands
      } else {
         op2 = stack.pop();
         op1 = stack.pop();
         piece = "("+op1+symbol+op2+")";
         stack.push(piece);
      }      
   }
}

if (stack.count == 1) {
   stack.pop() is the INFIX
} else {
   ERROR
}
```

Of course if you want to consider unary operators, the conditions have to be a little more structured to consider the stack with a single element

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full Ruby implementation of the algorithm mentioned:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

parts = gets.strip.split(/ +/)

stack = [ ]

parts.each do |part|
  if part =~ /\D/  # it's a binary operation
    right_operand = stack.pop
    left_operand = stack.pop
    stack.push("(#{left_operand} #{part} #{right_operand})")
  else             # it's a number
    stack.push(part)
  end
end

if stack.size == 1
  result = stack[0][1..-2]  # remove outer parentheses
  puts result
  exit(0)
else
  puts "parse error, stack does not contain exactly one element"
  exit(1)
end
```

Use like this:

```
echo '13 1 - 2 / 3 5 + *' | ruby postfix-to-infix.rb
```

This example produces the result:

```
((13 - 1) / 2) * (3 + 5)
```